# How would a creature evolve a antimagic field?

Tags: biology, magic, creature-design

I've been designing a group of creatures which one of their defining traits is that magic tends to become disabled once its close enough to them like a anti-magic field. The question I've been asking recently is how exactly would this work biologically without any magic involved?

Currently the explanation for this I have is that they produce some substance in their hide that causes magic to return to a harmless/base state of sorts, but I'm looking for alternative explanations as well to explain how this natural anti-magic works.

Magic in the world works with a mana system of sorts, with mages being able to use the mana found in the world to cast magic with the mana transforming to make the effect itself possible. Magical items are enchanted with mana to enable them to use magical effects that they otherwise wouldn't be able to.

Comment: It's kind of impossible to explain this without an explanation of how _magic_ works in your world.  If you're asking _why_ it might have evolved, if magic is hazardous in your world an anti-magic defense is a natural evolutionary path that might be explored.  But _how_ would basically be "because magic", unless you have a consistent system it can work against.

Comment: since this also depends on how your magic works this is a text book example of too opinion based.

Comment: How to make magic *not* work is totally unanswerable without any rules or information about how magic works in the first place.

Comment: Alright, just updated the post to explain in more detail on the magic system in question.

Comment: The title is asking "how would it evolve" where the text is asking "how would this work biologically".  The former is answerable in a generic kind of way "the creatures keep getting attacked with magic and so natural selection favours those with an anti-magic mutation" but the latter is still unanswerable with the level of detail provided.

Comment: "...how exactly would [disabling magic] work biologically without any magic involved?" To flip the question around: what, in the nature of your magic system, makes it vulnerable to being stopped by a non-magic biological process? If you don't have that information, we certainly don't. If you _do_, you haven't told us yet.

Comment: Let me try putting it another way. Magic is a force that works according to whatever set of rules you, the author, make up. If you say, "this creature nullifies the magic around it because of [insert reason here]", well, that's a rule you're making up for how the magic works. So asking how the creature can block it "without any magic involved" is confusing; the "blockability" of the magic (if any) is a property of the magic itself, regardless of whether you consider the creature to be "magical" or "ordinary".

Answer (score 2):

## Mana Absorption

The antimagic creature possesses a peculiar organ in its body which has the function of moving mana into the body, presumably to transform it into biologically useful energy

One side effect is that a small region around the creature ends up wholly devoid of any mana, and hence any spell that ends up near it quickly loses its energy, just as water in a vacuum swiftly evaporates

Comment: Looking at this more, I wonder if it could be used for certain plants/plant like organisms for cases where they have little to no sunlight.